# self.included in a module

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming, mixins

I have a class `Brand` that includes a module `SimpleURLSanitizer`. The module has a class method defined as below:

```
class Brand
  include SimpleURLSanitizer
end

module SimpleURLSanitizer
  def self.included base
    base.send :extend, self
  end
end
```

Since we are including the module, it will only have access to the module's instance methods. But the class method `included` will be called when the module is included in the class. The `base` is the `Brand` class. What is this `included` method doing? Is the `self` inside this method referring to the module or the `Brand` class? How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're including `SimpleURLSanitizer` in a class, all the methods of `SimpleURLSanitizer` will be accessible as instance method. This is the default behavior.

The `included` part is also making sure that, you can access those methods as class methods.

Comment: `self` inside the `included` method is referring to the `Brand` class?

Comment: No that's referring to the module `SimpleURLSanitizer`. But `base` is referring to `Brand` class.

Answer (score 1):

The `base` and `self` refer to `Brand` and `SimpleURLSanitizer`, respectively. The command will be expanded as:

```
Brand.send(:extend, SimpleURLSanitizer)
```

which can be rewritten as:

```
class Brand
  extend SimpleURLSanitizer
end
```

and means that the instance methods of `SimpleURLSanitizer` will also become class methods of `Brand`.